# Python regex - Ignore parenthesis as indexing?

Tags: python, regex, findall

I've currently written a nooby regex pattern which involves excessive use of the "(" and ")" characters, but I'm using them for 'or' operators, such as (A|B|C) meaning A or B or C.

I need to find every match of the pattern in a string.
Trying to use the `re.findall(pattern, text)` method is no good, since it interprets the parenthesis characters as indexing signifiers (or whatever the correct jargon be), and so each element of the produced List is not a string showing the matched text sections, but instead is a tuple (which contain very ugly snippets of pattern match).

Is there an argument I can pass to `findall` to ignore paranthesis as indexing?
Or will I have to use a very ugly combination of `re.search`, and `re.sub`

(This is the only solution I can think of; Find the index of the re.search, add the matched section of text to the List then remove it from the original string {by using ugly index tricks}, continuing this until there's no more matches. Obviously, this is horrible and undesirable).

Thanks!

Comment: Can you just show us samples what you try to match/catch and what not?

Comment: Probably your regexp can be improved =)

Comment: For example, `re.findall(r"(A|B|C)D", "BDE")` returns ['B'] instead of ['AD']

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Yes, add `?:` to a group to make it non-capturing.

```
import re
print re.findall('(.(foo))', "Xfoo")   # [('Xfoo', 'foo')]
print re.findall('(.(?:foo))', "Xfoo") # ['Xfoo']
```

See [re syntax](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html#regular-expression-syntax) for more information.

Comment: Just inside the parenthesis? For example, "(?:A|B|C)"?

Comment: @AntiEarth: yes, see examples

Comment: Will escaped parenthesis cause indexing? Eg: r"\\(this is in brackets\\)"

Comment: An unescaped parenthesis has a special meaning (except within a character class). Escaping the parenthesis is a way to say that you want the actual parenthesis character.

Answer (score 1):

```
re.findall(r"(?:A|B|C)D", "BDE")
```

or

```
re.findall(r"((?:A|B|C)D)", "BDE")
```